# Insert and update data automatically into SQL table from another table

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-jdbc

I have 2 tables and I want to update the first table with data after that the second table will be updated automatically.
I'm a beginner in spring boot and I really need your help.

I could insert data from table 1 to table 2 but if I update some data from table 1 then table 2 coudn't be updated.

What can I do?

This is what I have done so far: The two entities of the tables and the service I worked with to insert data into table 2 from table 1.

Table 1:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "formation")
   public class Formation {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String cursus;
private String groupeaction;
private String module;
private String formateur;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
private Long nbrappart;
private Long nbrabsent;
private Long hf;
private Long jf;
private Long nbrheures;
private Long tauxh;
private Long ristourneprevis;
private Long couthebergttc;
private Long coutpausecafttc;
```

Table 2:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "tablef")
   public class Tablef {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String cursus;
private Long nbrappart;
    private Long Sumnbrheures;
    private Long Sumjf;
    private Long jhf;
    private String groupeaction;
```

the service i used :

```
public Boolean InserIntoTableF(Tablef tf) {
Long id = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong();
tf.setId(id);
jdbc.execute("insert into tablef (id,cursus,groupeaction 
   ,nbrappart,sumnbrheures,sumjf,jhf)\r\n" + 
"select   id,cursus,groupeaction,nbrappart,sum(nbrheures),sum(jf) 
            ,sum(jf)*nbrappart\r\n" + 
        " from formation \r\n" + 
        "group by cursus ;");
return true;


}
```

The controller :

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
  @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/api")
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
 public class FormationController {
  @Autowired
  private FormationService formationservice;

  @Autowired
   private FormationRepository formationrepository;
 @GetMapping("/formations")
public List<Formation> GetAll() {
    return formationrepository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/formations/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Formation> getFormationById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long formationId)
        throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Formation formation = formationrepository.findById(formationId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Formation not found for this id :: " + formationId));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(formation);
}

@PostMapping("/formations")
public Formation createFormation(@Valid @RequestBody Formation formation) {
    return formationrepository.save(formation);
}
// this is how i update my entity formation (table 1)
@PutMapping("/formations/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Formation> updateFormation(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long formationId,
        @Valid @RequestBody Formation formationDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Formation formation = formationrepository.findById(formationId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Formation not found for this id :: " + formationId));

    formation.setCursus(formationDetails.getCursus());
    formation.setGroupeaction(formationDetails.getGroupeaction());
    formation.setModule(formationDetails.getModule());
    formation.setFormateur(formationDetails.getFormateur());
    formation.setDate(formationDetails.getDate());
    formation.setNbrappart(formationDetails.getNbrappart());
    formation.setNbrabsent(formationDetails.getNbrabsent());
    formation.setHf(formationDetails.getHf());
    formation.setJf(formationDetails.getJf());
    formation.setNbrheures(formationDetails.getNbrheures());
    formation.setTauxh(formationDetails.getTauxh());
    formation.setRistourneprevis(formationDetails.getRistourneprevis());
    formation.setCouthebergttc(formationDetails.getCouthebergttc());
    formation.setCoutpausecafttc(formationDetails.getCoutpausecafttc());
    final Formation updatedFormation = formationrepository.save(formation);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedFormation);
}

@DeleteMapping("/formations/{id}")
public Map<String, Boolean> deleteFormation(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long formationId)
        throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Formation formation = formationrepository.findById(formationId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + formationId));

    formationrepository.delete(formation);
    Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
    return response;
}
@PostMapping(value = "/fileupload")
public ResponseEntity<Formation> uploadFile(@ModelAttribute Formation formation) {

    Boolean isFlag=formationservice.saveDataFromFile(formation.getFile());
    if(isFlag) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

    }else

    return   new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
  // here where i inser data from formation(table1) to tablef (table2)
   @PostMapping(value = "/test")
 public Boolean AddTf(Tablef tf) {
  return formationservice.InserIntoTableF(tf);
```

}

}

Comment: write the same plain sql query to update 2 table, when you update table 1

Comment: i update the controller to show how i update my table 1 (formation) .how can i update the table 2 automatically with the table 1? @yvoytovych

Comment: i mean in `updateEmployee` call 2 methods `repo.updateFormation(id, formationDetails)` and `repo.updateTablef(id, formationDetails )` - which would be sql: `update [table] set [attribtues] where id = id`

Answer (score -1):

If you use spring boot jpa to persist your data then you can have a look at JPA EntityListener and @PostPersist

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private String field;

  public MyEntity() { }


}
```

The MyEntityListener impl

```
public class MyEntityListener {


  @PostPersist
  void onPostPersist(MyEntity myEntity) {
      // save data to second table that needs an update on myEntity save 
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear could you explain more  or show me an example plz @Tan